# How do I add images in laravel view?

Tags: php, laravel

The thing is, my image is not directly present in my view

```
Route::Get('saakshar',function()
{
return view('version1');
});
```

and in my version1.blade.php

```
<?php
include(app_path()."/../resources/views/fronthead.blade.php");
?>
```

I know using php commands in blade file is not efficient or good in any manner, but blade command is not working, but that's not my main problem here.

and in my fronthead.blade.php

```
<img src='app_path()."/../resources/views/photos/logo.png"' alt="no logo">
```

I haven't learned fully the blade language, so for time being i am using php commands.

But my problem is, why isn't the photo loading in the webpage? Is the URL wrong? Did I place the "photos" folder in the wrong place?

Edit: I've even tried to place the photo is the same folder as fronthead.blade.php and changed the src tag.

I've even tried giving a separate Route::Get() from fronthead.blade.php, but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should store your images, css and JS files in a `public` directory. To create a link to any of them, use `asset()` helper:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/myimage.png') }}" alt="description of myimage">
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset

As alternative, you could use amazing [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) package for building forms and HTML elements, so your code will look like this:

```
{{ HTML::image('img/myimage.png', 'a picture') }}
```

Comment: where do i add the asset line? in img src attribute? if yes, i am not getting the image, it still shows me the alternate message

Comment: You should add it to `src`. Post your code please. Also go to web browser, click "show source code" and post generated HTML here too (that `<img ... >` part).

Comment: <img src="{{ asset('photos/logo.png')}}" alt="no logo">
So the logo.png is in public/asset/photos/logo.png 


this is what's in my view page source result

Comment: You mean you get this in a browser (with `view source`)? Or you copy-pasted this from your blade file? If you get this from browser, what's your blade file full name?

Comment: yes, from browser, rightclick->view page source.
my blade name is fronthead.blade.php.This fronthead.blade.php is being "Required" by my homepage view called as "version1.blade.php".

Comment: The problem is your blade template wasn't parsed by Blade. Do you use `@include(fronthead)` directive to include this file? Can you show full `fronthead` and `version1` file contents?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108752/discussion-between-vishwanth-iron-heart-and-alexey-mezenin).

Answer (score 10):

```
<img src="/images/yourfile.png">
```

Store your files in public/images directory.

Answer (score 7):

If  Image folder location is `public/assets/img/default.jpg.`
You can try in view

```
   <img src="{{ URL::to('/assets/img/default.jpg') }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

normaly is better image store in public folder (because it has write permission already that you can use when I upload images to it)

```
public
    upload_media
         photos
            image.png


$image  = public_path() . '/upload_media/photos/image.png'; // destination path
```

view PHP

```
<img src="<?= $image ?>">
```

View blade

```
<img src="{{ $image }}">
```

Comment: i tried this using php, and this time, there's no alternate message displayed too, when i inspected what's happening, it looks something like this
G:\mini\project\public/photos/logo.png